# Show an block Image before change the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show a block image all the time when the user click on a "a href" or on a "Button" before the ajax image load which means the user will not click in another button untill that page loads.

i've tried this code but it's not working i', i'm new on jquery, if somenone  can help with that I'll be graetful

```
<?php if($this->uri->segment(1) != 'pedidos'){ ?>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a, button').click(function(event){
         $('#bloqueio_tela').show();
         event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a, button').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#bloqueio_tela').show();
    });
});
```

It does exactly what it sounds like! Prevents the default event!